# How does the linux kernel manage less than 1GB physical memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm learning the linux kernel internals and while reading "Understanding Linux Kernel", quite a few memory related questions struck me. One of them is, how the Linux kernel handles the memory mapping if the physical memory of say only 512 MB is installed on my system.

As I read, kernel maps **0(or 16) MB-896MB** physical RAM into 0xC0000000 linear address and can directly address it. So, in the above described case where I only have 512 MB:

- How can the kernel map 896 MB from only 512 MB ? In the scheme described, the kernel set things up so that every process's page tables mapped virtual addresses from 0xC0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF (1GB) directly to physical addresses from 0x00000000 to 0x3FFFFFFF (1GB). But when I have only 512 MB physical RAM, how can I map, virtual addresses from 0xC0000000-0xFFFFFFFF to physical 0x00000000-0x3FFFFFFF ? Point is I have a physical range of only  0x00000000-0x20000000.
- What about user mode processes in this situation?
- Every article explains only the situation, when you've installed 4 GB of memory and the kernel maps the 1 GB into kernel space and user processes uses the remaining amount of RAM.

I would appreciate any help in improving my understanding.

Thanks..!

Comment: This would be a good question for unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: The virtual address kernel memory is mapped to need not necessarily be 0xC0000000.

Comment: 0xC0000000 was a default address for x86

Comment: osgx, Thanks for your comments. Definitely useful. Need to make sense of the pointers you have provided. Will get back with questions, if any. Thanks a lot.

Comment: TheLoneJoker, I can also recommend you a ` Linux Kernel Development` book by Robert Love. It consists of text, and not of code and comments to it, as it is for ULK

Comment: @TheLoneJoker : Did you get satisfactory answer to your question ? Actually we are also puzzled by the same query as your own.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Not all virtual (linear) addresses must be mapped to anything. If the code accesses unmapped page, the page fault is risen.

The physical page can be mapped to several virtual addresses simultaneously.

In the 4 GB virtual memory there are 2 sections: 0x0... 0xbfffffff - is process virtual memory and 0xc0000000 .. 0xffffffff is a kernel virtual memory.

- How can the kernel map 896 MB from only 512 MB ?

It maps up to 896 MB.  So, if you have only 512, there will be only 512 MB mapped.

If your physical memory is in 0x00000000 to 0x20000000, it will be mapped for direct kernel access to virtual addresses 0xC0000000 to 0xE0000000 (linear mapping).

- What about user mode processes in this situation?

Phys memory for user processes will be mapped (not sequentially but rather random page-to-page mapping) to virtual addresses 0x0 .... 0xc0000000. This mapping will be the second mapping for pages from 0..896MB. The pages will be taken from free page lists.

- Where are user mode processes in phys RAM?

Anywhere.

- Every article explains only the situation, when you've *installed 4 GB of memory* and the

No. Every article explains how 4 Gb of virtual address space is mapped. The size of virtual memory is always 4 GB (for 32-bit machine without memory extensions like PAE/PSE/etc for x86)

As stated in `8.1.3. Memory Zones` of the book  `Linux Kernel Development` by Robert Love (I use third edition), there are several zones of physical memory:

- ZONE_DMA - Contains page frames of memory below 16 MB
- ZONE_NORMAL - Contains page frames of memory at and above 16 MB and below 896 MB
- ZONE_HIGHMEM - Contains page frames of memory at and above 896 MB

So, if you have 512 MB, your ZONE_HIGHMEM will be empty, and ZONE_NORMAL will have 496 MB of physical memory mapped.

Also, take a look to `2.5.5.2. Final kernel Page Table when RAM size is less than 896 MB` section of the book. It is about case, when you have less memory than 896 MB.

Also, for ARM there is some description of virtual memory layout: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/arm/memory.txt

The line 63 `PAGE_OFFSET    high_memory-1` is the direct mapped part of memory

Comment: osgx, based on what you mentioned, "So, if you have 512 MB, your ZONE_NORMAL will have 496 MB of physical memory mapped." if that is the case, there will not remain any place for a user-space page in the physical memory. Unless, ZONE_NORMAL pages can be swapped out? Look forward to what you think.

Comment: @TheLoneJoker, Kernel can allocate phys pages for user space process both from phys. zones ZONE_NORMAL and ZONE_HIGHMEM. (e.g. as at http://linux-mm.org/HighMemory for 2G system: "It is important that the kernel allocates process and page cache memory from both zones") If ZONE_HIGHMEM is empty, kernel will allocate page from ZONE_NORMAL.

Comment: @TheLoneJoker, The swapping is a process on VIRTUAL Page, or, you can name it "unmapping virtual page from physical". So, any user page from virtual address space can be unmapped and swapped out.

Comment: @TheLoneJoker, HIGHMEM is a problem only for Kernel, for user process there is no difference between highmem- and normal- mapped pages.

Answer (score 17):

The hardware provides a [Memory Management Unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). It is a piece of circuitry which is able to intercept and alter any memory access. Whenever the processor accesses the RAM, e.g. to read the next instruction to execute, or as a data access triggered by an instruction, it does so at some *address* which is, roughly speaking, a 32-bit value. A 32-bit word can have a bit more than 4 billions distinct values, so there is an *address space* of 4 GB: that's the number of bytes which could have a unique address.

So the processor sends out the request to its memory subsystem, as "fetch the byte at address *x* and give it back to me". The request goes through the MMU, which decides what to do with the request. The MMU virtually splits the 4 GB space into *pages*; page size depends on the hardware you use, but typical sizes are 4 and 8 kB. The MMU uses tables which tell it what to do with accesses for each page: either the access is granted with a rewritten address (the page entry says: "yes, the page containing address *x* exists, it is in physical RAM at address *y*") or rejected, at which point the kernel is invoked to handle things further. The kernel may decide to kill the offending process, or to do some work and alter the MMU tables so that the access may be tried again, this time successfully.

This is the basis for *virtual memory*: from the point of view, the process has some RAM, but the kernel has moved it to the hard disk, in "swap space". The corresponding table is marked as "absent" in the MMU tables. When the process accesses his data, the MMU invokes the kernel, which fetches the data from the swap, puts it back at some free space in physical RAM, and alters the MMU tables to point at that space. The kernel then jumps back to the process code, right at the instruction which triggered the whole thing. The process code sees nothing of the whole business, except that the memory access took quite some time.

The MMU also handles access rights, which prevents a process from reading or writing data which belongs to other processes, or to the kernel. Each process has its own set of MMU tables, and the kernel manage those tables. Thus, each process has its own address space, as if it was alone on a machine with 4 GB of RAM -- except that the process had better not access memory that it did not allocate rightfully from the kernel, because the corresponding pages are marked as absent or forbidden.

When the kernel is invoked through a system call from some process, the kernel code must run within the address space of the process; so the kernel code must be somewhere in the address space of each process (but protected: the MMU tables prevent access to the kernel memory from unprivileged user code). Since code can contain hardcoded addresses, the kernel had better be at the *same* address for all processes; conventionally, in Linux, that address is 0xC0000000. The MMU tables for each process map that part of the address space to whatever *physical* RAM blocks the kernel was actually loaded upon boot. Note that the kernel memory is never swapped out (if the code which can read back data from swap space was itself swapped out, things would turn sour quite fast).

On a PC, things can be a bit more complicated, because there are 32-bit and 64-bit modes, and segment registers, and PAE (which acts as a kind of second-level MMU with huge pages). The basic concept remains the same: each process gets its own view of a virtual 4 GB address space, and the kernel uses the MMU to map each virtual page to an appropriate physical position in RAM, or nowhere at all.

Comment: Thomas, Is the kernel at very beginning of 0xc0000000 or it is a bit (several hundred MB) later?

Comment: Apparently, the kernel is linked with code starting at 0xC0000000 or not far beyond (e.g. 0xC0008000), at least on ARM and x86. However, the kernel also uses that 1GB area for its own data allocations, including dynamic blocks (`kmalloc()...`) and stacks for in-kernel threads, and I cannot tell how far towards high addresses those go...

Comment: but the first 896 MB of `0xC0000000-` are for mapped phys. pages? So, Kernel is stored at very low phys address?

Comment: The kernel must be stored in physical RAM (the kernel contains the code which can read things back from swap, so it cannot be swapped out itself, otherwise who would read it back from swap space ?). It is stored in RAM during bootup, at a time where the whole RAM is not necessarily available or fully detected (it depends on the architecture; but the bootloader is usually quite primitive). So the kernel tends to go to low physical addresses.

Comment: kernel is stored at low when bootloader does a jmp to it. But bootstrapping of kernel (function main and/or before) includes moving to higher address (after 32/64bit mode is activated, and memory is detected), because the smallest RAM is for ISA-like DMA. Kernel contains both code and data; and some data can be swapped out. In principle, some code can be swapped too (not the code which will handle page fault). There is a separate branch in handle_mm_fault for kernel's virtual addresses.

Answer (score 4):

osgx has an excellent answer, but I see a comment where someone still doesn't understand.

> Every article explains only the situation, when you've installed 4 GB
>   of memory and the kernel maps the 1 GB into kernel space and user
>   processes uses the remaining amount of RAM.

Here is much of the confusion.  There is **virtual memory** and there is **physical memory**.  Every 32bit CPU has 4GB of **virtual** memory.  The Linux kernel's traditional split was 3G/1G for user memory and kernel memory, but newer options allow different partitioning.

> Why distinguish between the kernel and user space? - my own question

When a task swaps, the MMU must be updated.  The kernel MMU space should remain the same for all processes.  The kernel must handle interrupts and fault requests at any time.

> How does virtual to physical mapping work? - my own question.

There are many permutations of virtual memory.

- a single private mapping to a physical RAM page.
- a duplicate virtual mapping to a single physical page.
- a mapping that throws a *SIGBUS* or other error.
- a mapping backed by disk/swap.

From the above list, it is easy to see why you may have more **virtual** address space than physical memory.  In fact, the *fault handler* will typically inspect process memory information to see if a page is **mapped** (I mean allocated for the process), but not *in memory*.  In this case the fault handler will call the I/O sub-system to read in the page.  When the page has been read and the MMU tables updated to point the virtual address to a new physical address, the process that caused the fault resumes.

If you understand the above, it becomes clear why you would like to have a larger **virtual** mapping than physical memory.  It is how memory swapping is supported.

There are other uses.  For instance two processes may use the same code library.  It is possible that they are at different **virtual addresses** in the process space due to linking.  You may map the different **virtual addresses** to the same **physical page** in this case in order to save physical memory.  This is quite common for new allocations; they all point to a physical 'zero page'.  When you touch/write the memory the zero page is copied and a new physical page allocated (COW or copy on write).

It is also sometimes useful to have the virtual pages aliased with one as **cached** and another as **non-cached**.  The two pages can be examined to see what data is cached and what is not.

Mainly **virtual** and **physical** are not the same!  Easily stated, but often confusing when looking at the Linux VMM code.

Answer (score 3):

-

Hi, actually, I don't work on x86 hardware platform, so there may exist some technical errors in my post.

To my knowledge, the range between 0(or 16)MB - 896MB is listed specially while you have more RAM than that number, say, you have 1GB physical RAM on your board, which is called "low-memory". If you have more physical RAM than 896MB on your board, then, rest of the physical RAM is called highmem.

Speaking of your question, there are 512MiBytes physical RAM on your board, so actually, there is no 896, no highmem.

The total RAM kernel can see and also can map is 512MB.

'Cause there is 1-to-1 mapping between physical memory and kernel virtual address, so there is 512MiBytes virtual address space for kernel.  I'm really not sure whether or not the prior sentence is right, but it's what in my mind.

What I mean is if there is 512MBytes, then the amount of physical RAM the kernel can manage is also 512MiBytes, further, the kernel cannot create such big address space like beyond 512MBytes.

Refer to user space, there is one different point, pages of user's application can be swapped out to harddisk, but pages of the kernel cannot.

So, for user space, with the help of page tables and other related modules, it seems there is still 4GBytes address space. 
Of course, this is virtual address space, not physical RAM space.

This is what I understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the physical memory is less than 896 MB then the linux kernel maps upto that physical address lineraly.

For details see this.. http://learnlinuxconcepts.blogspot.in/2014/02/linux-addressing.html