# Memory Allocation for Kernel Space and User Space processes

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, device-driver, systems-programming

```
Is there any difference between kernel space & user space MEMORY ALLOCATIONS?
From which region of memory they get allocated.
```

Can anyone please provide some pointers on this?

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Sandeep Singh

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the linux kernel manage less than 1GB physical memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528568/how-does-the-linux-kernel-manage-less-than-1gb-physical-memory) -- the question I selected has some details about `512M` memory that's not in this question, and the target is tagged [tag:arm], but the answers are quite good there... please read it and see if you agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory regions for both the regions are governed by the respective address-space ranges. The boundary value is stored in the fence register.

Answer (score 1):

User and kernel memory does have differences:   in the sense of having different physical attributes tagged to it:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87625/what-is-difference-between-user-space-and-kernel-space

But for allocation algorithm itself:  userspace memory is always falling back on kernel memory for its ultimate implementation.

And because kernel mode memory is so much more powerful than usermode, there is a hardware mechanism called SMEP to prevent executing usermode memory from inside kernel mode:

https://www.ncsi.com/nsatc11/presentations/wednesday/emerging_technologies/fischer.pdf

And hardware features like NX bit is always controlled from the kernel mode (ring 0): as a normal user (ring 3) you will not be able to access the bit.

More hardware features:

http://hypervsir.blogspot.sg/2014/11/page-structure-table-corruption-attacks.html